# Cassandra system.migrations and system.schemas columnfamily - configure ttl of data to be kept

Tags: cassandra

I am doing frequent Schema changes in my Cassandra cluster. This leads to quite large Migrations-hc* and Schema-hc* files in the cassandra/data/system directory.

Does anyone know if there is a way to configure the amount of schema history data to be kept in those columnfamilies? For how long is this data stored by default?

Thanks alot!